# Outputting files in R without overwriting

Tags: r, write.table

The project I'm working on requires creating an automated script that will connect to my database table (which updates daily) and gets that table into R and I output it to a certain directory under a certain name. Well, the main idea of the project is to keep a history of all these tables so we can start using them, but it will overwrite everyday.

The code :

```
table<- sqlQuery(channel, "Select * From table")

write.table(table, file="C:/DailyReport/data.xlsx")
```

So the question : How can I set the write.table function to not overwrite everyday? (I am open to any solutions)

Comment: What do you want it to do instead? Generate a new file name? Append data? How are you using `write.table` to create an xlsx file?

Comment: I'm using write.table exactly the way I showed in the question...?

But I do NOT want to append but maybe generate a new file name. @AnandaMahto

Comment: You'll have to decide what you want to do in the case that the file exists before anybody can help you. You can check to see _if_ the file exists using `file.exists()`.

Comment: Well, your "xlsx" isn't going to really be an Excel file (even though you would be able to read it in Excel), so I just thought I should ask and make sure we were on the same page. Shadow's suggestion is otherwise a reasonable alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about appending `Sys.Date()` to the filename?

```
write.table(table, file=paste0("C:/DailyReport/data-", Sys.Date(), ".xlsx"))
```

Comment: That works, well, you're missing the last ")" at the end but yeah it works. Except when I open the file it says it's corrupted. Any ideas for that?

Comment: It opened fine before I used paste0 though... @AnandaMahto

Comment: I can't get either version to work. Why don't you use `write.csv2` and a `.csv` ending instead?

Comment: @NealC, try opening up the file in notepad or a basic text editor. Is everything there? I would suggest that you look at `write.csv` or something if you plan to work with the data in Excel.

Comment: The formatting with write.csv2 is horrible. Now that I have your idea of appending Sys.Date() to the file name, I think I can figure it out from here! Thank you!

Comment: I used just write.csv instead of write.csv2 and it looks fine. Thanks for the help shadow and @AnandaMahto